# Passar lista de produtos para outra Activity

Tags: java, android, lista, intent

Olá, estou aprendendo e queria a sugestão de vocês, de uma forma simples a principio, de como fazer essa passagem de produtos para outra Activity. O aplicativo que estou desenvolvendo ele carrega uma lista de produtos de um WebService, então no aplicativo não tem cadastro de produtos, apenas a leitura dos produtos disponíveis e ao fazer essa leitura já é carregado os produtos no Firebase, onde também armazeno os clientes que podem ser cadastrados no aplicativo. 
  Então quando alguém vai criar um pedido novo, a minha ideia é que tenha três etapas. A primeira é a escolha do cliente que vai fazer o pedido, depois o ou os produtos que vão ser pedidos, e na última tela onde aparece todas as informações (cliente, produto e as informações do produto: como valor total...). Na tela de escolher os produtos ele já carrega as informações do Firebase, usando o FirebaseUI (Talvez não seja a melhor forma, mas até agora funcionou bem com o cliente e é bem rápido para carregar) a função que uso para carregar o RecyclerView dos produtos é essa:

```
public void setupRecycler(){


    adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Produto, ProdutoHolder>(
            Produto.class,
            R.layout.recyclerview_items,
            ProdutoHolder.class,
            ref
    ) {
        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(final ProdutoHolder viewHolder, final Produto model, final int position) {
            viewHolder.setId(model.getId().toUpperCase());
            viewHolder.setNome(model.getNome());
            viewHolder.setDescricao(model.getDescricao());
            viewHolder.setTamanho(model.getTamanho());
            viewHolder.setQuantidade(model.getQuantidade());
            viewHolder.setValor(model.getValor());


            viewHolder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override

                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - lastClickTime < 1500){
                        viewHolder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);

                        return;
                    }
                    lastClickTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
                    viewHolder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);

                    String idProduto = model.getId();
                    String nomeProduto = model.getNome();
                    String descricaoProduto = model.getDescricao();
                    String tamanhoProduto = model.getTamanho();
                    String quantidadeProduto = model.getQuantidade();
                    String valorProduto = model.getValor();




                }
            });




        }
    };

    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Fotos das etapas:
[[PEDIDO]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0icU4.png)
[[ESCOLHER CLIENTE]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YshxL.png)
[[ESCOLHER PRODUTO]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J8sye.png)
[[TELA FINAL(ainda não terminada)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hYQf5.png)

Esse OnClick estava usando para teste, mas funciona legal assim também, dentro do próprio adapter ele consegue pegar as informações do produto, mas como posso passar todas essas informações para outra Activity, e se for mais de um produto? Pensei em usar JSON, fiz até alguns testes, mas não funcionou, estou com bastante dúvida, como não precisa fazer alteração de nada do produto, apenas passar as informações do produto, então talvez um Array já resolva. Bom essa é minha dúvida, Sempre tem ajudado as vezes que faço uma pergunta aqui, então Obrigadoo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Utilize `Seriazable` ou `Parceable`(Mais recomendado), são interfaces padrões uma do *Java* mesmo e outra padrão *Android* para poder serializar objetos em tempo de execução.

Answer (score 1):

sim, um array resolve, voce preenche ele com as suas variáveis no adapter e depois passa esse array para a outra activity em um bundle, algo tipo isso:

```
public List<String> minhasEscolhas = new ArrayList<String>();
// voce pode criar essa variável no inicio da activity mas dentro da declaração de classe
public void setupRecycler(){
    // ...
    @Override
    protected void populateViewHolder(final ProdutoHolder viewHolder, final Produto model, final int position) {
        // ...
        viewHolder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override

            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - lastClickTime < 1500){
                        viewHolder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                        return;
                    }
                    lastClickTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();                        viewHolder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);

                    String idProduto = model.getId();
                    String nomeProduto = model.getNome();
                    String descricaoProduto = model.getDescricao();
                    String tamanhoProduto = model.getTamanho();
                    String quantidadeProduto = model.getQuantidade();
                    String valorProduto = model.getValor();

                    minhasEscolhas.Add(idProduto);
                    minhasEscolhas.Add(nomeProduto);
                    // ...
                    minhasEscolhas.Add(oQueVoceQiser);
                  }
            });
        }
    };
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter); 
}
```

Uma vez preenchido o array, voce passa ele pro intent da activity que voce vai chamar:

```
public void emUmEventoOnClickqueChamaActityQualquer() {
        Bundle data = new Bundle();
        data.putParcelableArrayList("produtos", minhasEscolhas);
        // aqui passa a lista para o bundle
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityQueQueroChamarComOArrayDeProdutos.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        intent.putExtras(data);
        startActivity(intent);
}
```

Depois no oncreate da "ActivityQueQueroChamarComOArrayDeProdutos" voce pega o parâmetro passado pelo bundle e distribui como voce quiser na activity:

```
// ...
private List<String> minhasEscolhas = new ArrayList<String>();
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        minhasEscolhas = extras.getParcelableArrayList("produtos");
        // ...
    }
//...
```

Lenbrando que quando declarou a variavel **`public List<String> minhasEscolhas = new ArrayList<String>();`** na activity pai, voce também pode pegar essa variável na activity filha, mas eh melhor voce passar pelo bundle porque assim a activty de origem fica liberada

espero que ajude!

Comment: Isso não passa um Array de Produto mas sim um de String.

Comment: sim, é verdade amigo @ramaral, mas ele pediu para esclarecer a duvida, e isso a reposta fez, porque independente do tipo de array que estiver passando, o processo de transporte é o mesmo, pois ele pode preencher um "hashmap" com o produto, que vai ter ser enviado via bundle da mesma forma que está na resposta.

Comment: Apenas com as informações dadas na resposta, se em vez de `ArrayList<String>` for  utilizado `ArrayList<Produto>`, não vai funcionar

Comment: se ele tiver uma classe Produto para passar como Tipo para o ArrayList<Produto> vai funcionar da mesma forma, mas eu me baseei no código que ele postou, dai, onde ele passa os valores do produto ele passa uma String para cada dado, ex.: `String idProduto = model.getId();String nomeProduto = model.getNome(); ...` e por ai vai, por isso respondi como um array de string